# Showing results with the form and results in the same blade - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that allows the user to search for data, and this data should show in the same page/blade. I'm passing the results that should show in the same page, as shown below.
I receive an error as I try to open the page as shown below.
If I'm showing the results in another page, it works fine.

Passing results into the blade :

```
@foreach($post_srch as $post_s)
<a href=""> 
<h4> {{$post_s->title}}  </h4>
</a>
@endforeach
```

Error :

```
Undefined variable: post_srch (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffSpot\resources\views\updates.blade.php)
```

Controller return code :

```
return view('test', ['post_srch' => $posts]);
```

How can I tell the page to ignore the variables during page loading, but process/show the variable when I click on the search button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the variables exists before the foreach:

```
if (isset($post_srch))
{
    // The foreach.
}
```